# Auto-comment Close Reasons

Tags: script, comments, closing

### Description

This script will automagically fill the comment box for you when you vote to close with the reason you are voting to close for! That way the user that asked the question can know what is wrong with their question so that they can fix it.

It will include bold, italics, and links in the comment.

The comment box will be filled, but it won't automatically send the comment - you can choose whether or not you want to add the comment.

### Download

You can download this [on userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/172816).

### Screenshot

---

[image: screenshot]

---

### Minified Source Code (full source [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/172816))

```
var sEl=document.createElement("script");sEl["textContent"in sEl?"textContent":"text"]="("+function(){$(document).on("click",".popup-submit",function(){$(".question").find(".comments-link").click();var e=$(".action-selected").find("[class^=action-]").last().html();e=e.replace(/<span.*class="bounty-indicator-tab.*<\/span>/,"").trim().replace(/<\/?b>/g,"**").replace(/<\/?i>/g,"*").replace(/<a href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/g,"[$2]($1)");$(".question").find("textarea").text(e)})}+")()";document.head.appendChild(sEl);sEl.parentNode.removeChild(sEl)
```

Bug reports and feedback will be appreciated!

Comment: This looks like nearly the same functionality as ["Auto-Add A Comment When Closing"](http://stackapps.com/q/4192/7653).

Comment: The source code link is dead, has been for >year.

Comment: Unlike "Auto-Add A Comment When Closing", this one still works, and gives you a chance to edit the comment before submitting.

Comment: The source link should be changed to `userscripts-mirror.org`.